# Apache Redirect Performance - .htaccess vs Apache configuration file ?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wonder if having many redirect rules inside a .haccess file ( let say 10000+ ) could be a performance issue. ( this file is parsed every access to the site )

Storing them in the Apache configuration file would not be a better option ( on performance point of view) ?

Answer (score 1):

Storing that in the Apache config is the better option in this case, since you don't have to read the .htaccess file on every access; the config is read once, then kept in memory.

Please note, however, that you won't be able to change your redirects on the fly.  You'll have to restart the server for them to become effective.

Also, when you're worried about performance on that level, it makes sense to disable .htaccess files altogether, since Apache will search your directories (from the directory it's serving, up to /) for a .htaccess file.  `AllowOverride None` on `<Directory />` should do the job, and then don't enable it anywhere else.